# Meaning of words "заштырить" and "отштырить"

Tags: перевод

[image: Показание положения радиотелескопа на блоке электропривода азимутального и угломестного вращения]

I could only find an explanation of the root word **штырить**, which according to this reference https://otvet.mail.ru/question/91415603, means "to be inspired/energized by something". So perhaps **заштырить** means to "turn off power and **отштырить** means to "turn on power" to the radio telescope. However, there is a switch next to these buttons which indicates "turn on" and "turn off". And there's also the red "stop" button. The only other references to these two words that I could find had something to do with electrical power systems.

Comment: the answer at Mail.ru describes the slang meaning of the word, here we either deal with a technical term or with a joke created by editing the image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The photo presents *"Пульт управления заштыривающим устройством для фиксации поворотной части радиотелескопа."*
So, there is indeed a "штырь" (pin, rod) that serves as some sort of a "handbrake" for the antenna and the two buttons are used to apply and release it.

The СТОП button is presumably used to stop the rotation.

See also: https://spbvedomosti.ru/news/country_and_world/krasavchik_ves_v_belom/, search for "заштырено".

And here: https://masterok.livejournal.com/2490572.html, search for "заштырены" in comments.

ПИУИ - Блок преобразователей интерфейса и индикации угловых координат.

БУК-М has nothing to do with the military anti-aircraft complex of the same name:

> Структура системы управления электроприводом а.с. представлена на рис.
>   2. Управление электроприводом радиотелескопа происходит в следующем порядке. Команды от центрального компьютера радиотелескопа [11—13]
>   передаются на рабочую станцию контроля и управления (РСКУ), далее на
>   аппаратуру автоматики системы наведения, которая обеспечивает
>   управление силовыми устройствами электропривода. В состав аппаратуры
>   автоматики системы наведения входят блоки коммутации сигналов
>   управления, блоки возбуждения двигателей (БВД) и тиристорные
>   преобразователи (ТП) для питания якорных цепей двигателей
>   электропривода а.с. радиотелескопа. Коммутирующие устройства
>   автоматики системы наведения сосредоточены в соответствующих **блоках
>   управления и коммутации БУК-М** электропривода главного зеркала, БУК-КР
>   для контррефлектора радиотелескопа.

Источник: http://naukarus.com/sistema-navedeniya-radioteleskopa-rt-32

Finally, here is what appears to be the upper part of the OP's image:

[image: Устройство заштыривания]

Comment: Yes, this also agrees with the statement: "Механизмы заштыривания обычно используются для удержания и фиксации, например, зеркал антенн в обсерваториях..." source: https://kruzhok.diary.ru/p131047595.htm

Answer (score 4):

I believe it relates to the word `штырь` (a pin).
So `заштырить` means to apply the 'штырь' and `отштырить` means to release the 'штырь'.

Answer (score 1):

These two words `заштырить` and `отштырить` have the same root as you correctly noticed. This root is `штырь` what means `rod`.

Prefix `за` in this case means action to put something into, like in `забить` (hammer in), `задвинуть` (push) or `закрыть` (shut).

Prefix `от` in this case means action to draw something out, like in `отодвинуть` (move back) or `открыть` (open).

Answer (score -3):

Dmitry's answer should be expanded a bit :)

Both of the words are slang, and in most use cases, it is implied that the "pin" is male genitalia, as in - penis.

`Заштырить` would mean to complete action of inserting a male's reproductive organ (into somewhere or someone).

`Отштырить` would mean to take a full round of sexual acts against someone, in a brutal manner. Mush similar to synonyms (also slang), `отодрать`, `отъебать`, `отыметь` where prefix `от` is used to verbally increase the brutality of described/past/promised sex interaction as well as its completeness to the maximum possible extent: the number of ejculations and acts' continuation.

> `Я хочу тебе вштырить`
> I would like to insert inside you.
>
> `Я хочу тебя отштырить`
> I would like to have hardcore sex with you.

Comment: you think they'd use slang for captions on the panel of an electronic device?

Comment: Unfortunately, that’s exactly what happened.

Comment: how are you so sure, are you the one who designed the device?

Comment: If I design my own device and write `отыметь` or other well known slang word on a switch, this wouldn’t make it less of a slang word. If you simply google those words in Russian internet it’s clear on how they are mostly used and that’s what my answer is all about. It’s important to learn how the words are mostly used by language bearers. Surely you can’t make sexual intercourse with those buttons, hello :)

Comment: it's not a makeshift device, it's a control part of a БУК launch system manufactured officially so i think you're utterly wrong

Comment: … although we don’t know for sure whether this given electronic device isn’t a brutal sex war machine. It even has a red stop button, and allows launching “Бук-М” rocket into the opponent after defining proper angle. All while saying ПИУИ :)

Comment: now your comment doesn't make sense at all, sorry, unless the image was tempered with and these captions were edited in

Comment: It makes sense to those who understand that those switches are "photoshop" and the device pictured is a clear joke. Nobody in sane mind will use those slang words for switches.

Comment: if you think it's a фотожаба, it would make sense to indicate that in your reply

Comment: My reply is for the meaning of the words the OP asked, irrespective of their context/picture, it would be the same in most use cases.

Comment: the OP is seeing a device so it will be confusing to receive an answer about slang which is unrelated to electronic equipment... the verb штырить is used in the context of concrete casting so obviously the slang meaning isn't the only one possible, by the way the slang meaning you've chosen isn't the only one either

Comment: OP asked meanings for `ЗАштырить` and `Вштырить`. And not` [  ]штырить`. Lack of prefix or its presence in the Russian language many times makes for a completely different meaning.